# Big O notation algorithms

Tags: algorithm

[image]

I have this problem and I don't understand how the answer for quadratic/logarithm and Exponential order is 40, 15 & 100. I know the formulas for these are O(n2), O(log(n)), O(2n) but not able to correlate the answers with these formulas. What is n in this problem? Is it the size of the data set (20) or is it 2? Please let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

`n` refers to the size of the input; 10/20 in this case. But the important part is not the actual value of `n` but the ratio between the previous and current `n` (in this case, doubling the input).

- If the algorithm is O(1), doubling the size of the input doesn't change the result. (10 => 10)
- If the algorithm is O(n), doubling the input doubles the output. (10 => 20)
- If the algorithm is O(n^2), doubling the input quadruples the output. (10 => 40)
- If the algorithm is O(log(n)), doubling the input multiplies the output by log(2). (10 => 15)
- If the algorithm is O(k^n), doubling the input is like raising the output to the 2nd power. (10 => 100).

Comment: If the answer is useful, please consider upvoting it and marking it as accepted.